# Using mbrola voices with festival from the command-line

Tags: command-line, text-to-speech, festival, speech-dispatcher

I installed `apt install festival #Version: 1:2.5.0-5`
and `apt install mbrola-de{1..7} #Version: 3.3+dfsg-4`

**How can I make use of this German mbrola voices in festival?**